# Timing capacitor and resistors -Reg

Tags: capacitor, timing

I have this IC - [Advance regulating PWM](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/uc3524.pdf)

I would like to understand how does the timing resistor and capacitor section works. Sorry for the beginner question but I am unable to understand this section.

The resistor in the RC circuit, will determine the rate of capacitor charging and discharging and that too when R and C are connected in series.

But in this IC, it is given as The timing capacitor provides the ramp signal. How does the charging and discharging of the capacitor take place? I dont see the timing resistor part involved in doing this. Can someone please explain clearly.

Thanks

Comment: *How does the charging and discharging of the capacitor take place?* In the datasheet of the UC3524 on page 4 it is described how the IC works. As there is no more detailed information it is impossible to say how this exactly works on a transistor level. Anyway, **why** do you need to understand how this works? You use the IC as described in the datasheet and that is it.

Comment: It's and RC Sawtooth generator circuit.  Did you want to know how to make your own?

Comment: I just wanted how this IC works on a transistor level. That's why I had doubt in this section

Comment: A FET version of a programmable Unijunction with a current source and cap dump at some threshold.

Comment: Examine the original datasheet (from Signetics Corporation; since bought by Philipps, and now part of NXP??) on their NE/SE555 timer IC.

Comment: This chip generates it's own PWM signal (the OSCillator) that switches at a fixed frequency that is determined by the  Rt * Ct you mentioned.  This PWM signal (voltage, frequency, pulse width) acts as a control signal reference and feeds into one-side of the comparator.  The other side of the comparator is comprised of several feedback signals that will trigger the comparator on/off proportionally and thus modulate the output stage.

Answer (score 1):

The datasheet says that

> […] the amplifier output voltage is then compared to the linear voltage ramp at C<sub>T</sub>.

"Linear" implies that the capacitor is charged with a constant current. So R<sub>T</sub> is not simply connected in series, but is used to program a constant current source.

We do not know how that chip implements this current source. But if we assume a current source like this:
[image: Op-amp current source with pass transistor]
<sup>(source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_source))</sup>

Then we could make it programmable by replacing the Zener diode with the R<sub>T</sub> resistor and letting a constant current flow through it; the varying resistance will then result in a varying reference voltage.